# Does running a HTTPModule prevent IIS Logging?

Tags: asp.net, iis, httpmodule

We are running a site using a custom HTTPModule to do some URL Routing.

The problem is this sites traffic is not being logged by IIS.

Everything appears to be set up correctly, and other sites on the same server are logging. But the log folder for this site remains empty. (not even the W3SVC... folder is being created!)

Is this related to us running a HTTPModule, or is something else causing the problem. I can't find anything that says it would stop logging, or anything that says it won't.

Answer (score 3):

In a word, no.  You've got something else funny going on.  Are you absolutely sure logging is enabled and you are looking at the correct path?