# Which event occurs first, OnAuthorizeRequest of HttpModule or IIS logging

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, httpmodule, iis-logs

Let me explain the context first.

The below is my understanding so please do not troll me :)

I have a `HttpModule` which helps in url rewriting on event `OnAuthorizeRequest`.

So whenever a request comes in with say `www.mysite.com/abc/` the module rewrites it to its underlying template say `/abcTemplate.aspx` using `context.RewritePath`

Now, when I check my IIS logs i.e. `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles` I am not able to find `/abc/` anywhere but a lot of `/abcTemplate.aspx`

So, a couple of questions

1. Is `/abc/` ever getting logged on IIS. If yes then where?
2. If no then does that mean that the event in `HttpModule` occurs before `IIS logging`?

I found a link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410838/does-running-a-httpmodule-prevent-iis-logging) but it does not completely answer my query.

Other than the above, I tried to search on the internet but not getting any relevant results.

Probably I am not typing in the correct keywords.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried Freb? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS Logging logs the request after the response has been prepared. Check this event life cycle.

[image]

[Source MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx)

In your case **RewritePath** is happening first and in a very later stage of the event life cycle the IIS is logging the details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should enable rewrite log

You can refer form here, check **Configure Failed Request Tracing** for setup IIS trace for rewrite
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules